# Read data from s3 using local machine - pyspark

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3, pyspark

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import boto3
import os
import pandas as pd

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

hadoop_conf = spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.access.key", "myaccesskey")
hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.secret.key", "mysecretkey")
hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "s3.amazonaws.com")
hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.BasicAWSCredentialsProvider")
hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.connection.ssl.enabled", "true")

conn = boto3.resource("s3", region_name="us-east-1")

df = spark.read.csv("s3a://mani-test-1206/test/test.csv", header=True)
df.show()

spark.stop()
```

when running above code I had below error:
 `java.io.IOException: From option fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.BasicAWSCredentialsProvider not found`

Hadoop and aws jars program is using:

spark-hadoop-distribution: `spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2`

```
hadoop jars:
hadoop-annotations-3.2.0.jar
hadoop-auth-3.2.0.jar
hadoop-aws-3.2.0.jar
hadoop-client-api-3.3.1.jar
hadoop-client-runtime-3.3.1.jar
hadoop-common-3.2.0.jar
hadoop-hdfs-3.2.0.jar

aws jars:
aws-java-sdk-1.11.624.jar
aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.624.jar
aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.624.jar
aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.624.jar
```

Any help will be highly appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem.
What helps me:

- update hadoop-aws-3.2.0 to 3.2.2 version
- use "fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider": "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider" (it looks name change)

Comment: Thanks the 2nd point really helped me.

Comment: Hi, how do I check what version of hadoop-aws I have and how do I update it? I am sorry if this is a silly question but I am new to spark/hadoop so I am not that familiar with the way things are done.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set [instance profile (one type of IAM roles)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2_instance-profiles.html) properly to the ec2 instance where you execute the codes.

so it has no proper permission to access nominted s3 bucket.

Second, review the java library if it is latest and supports to [get aws credential from instance profile](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/java-dg-roles.html).

Comment: Are you sure that " local machine" would be an EC2 instance?

Comment: Yes, the error clearly mentioned it: `IAMInstanceCredentialsProvider` not found

Comment: `java.io.IOException: From option fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.BasicAWSCredentialsProvider not found`
when I set this property `hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.BasicAWSCredentialsProvider")` else `IAMInstanceCredentialsProvider` as mentioned in the question

Comment: Also, the credentials I'm using are admin credentials, has s3:* access.
I'm not running from ec2 instance, I'm running from my laptop. Updated error in question.

Comment: so that's why you get the problem. Your code need understand and flexible enough if the instance itself doesn't have ec2 instance profile (such as run from your laptop), it can still get credentials from laptop's credential, such as `~/.aws/credentials` or AWS ENV `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`, etc